# publish_stream permission & APP access_token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

I've been digging through all docs I can find, but I cannot seem to verify this..

When I'm doing app authorization I'm asking for publish_stream from my visitor.
From to FB docs (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/):

> Enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's stream and to the streams  of the user's friends. With this permission, you can publish content to a user's feed **at any  time, without requiring offline_access**. However, please note that Facebook recommends a user- initiated sharing model.

It very explicitly states that I'm able to post at ANY time. But, a regular user access token expires after a certain time. So that won't be usable to post.

However, an APPLICATION access token can be retrieved at any time, without any user interaction. And when I've tested, I can successfully publish to a users feed (yes on their feed, not my applications feed) using the app access token. 
I haven't waited 2+ hours for the initially obtained User token to expire though, but even if the user session was logged out, I was still able to post using the app token.

So, this is what I want, right? Yes!

But this is not documented anywhere, so my question is:

Is this an allowed/recommended approach? Will I run into any problems around this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the right way to do it, so you'll not run into any problems etc.
Just use the App access_token to publish on you app users walls.

Greetings,
Fredyy

Comment: Thank you,
do you perhaps have any documentation pointing to this? Just don't want to write a solution based on this approach and then find out that Facebook suddenly decides to remove the functionality ("Hey, it was never documented and thus never existed").

Comment: As you quoted in your Post `With this permission, you can publish content to a user's feed at any time, without requiring offline_access` you can always post to the the users feed and this is only possible with the app access_token as the user access_token is only valid for limited time. But this is not documented correctly, like most functions of the Facebook Graph-API

Comment: Okay, I guess thats a good an answer as any. Too bad the documentttion is lacking :/
Thank you!